# Is it possible to simulate a distribution from a glm fit in statsmodels?

Tags: python, statistics, statsmodels

I would like to fit a multiple linear regression. It will have a couple input parameters and no intercept.

Is it possible to fit a glm fit with statsmodels then use that fit to simulate a distribution of predicted values?

Comment: which family?  Do you mean OLS or generalized linear model?

Comment: glm Gaussian is what I am looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the next, upcoming 0.14 release, there is a `get_distribution` method based on predicted distribution parameters that return an instance of a scipy or scipy compatible distribution class. The methods of those include `rvs` for simulating data. (excluding Tweedie family for which no distribution class exists yet)

Some of this is already available in earlier version.

For some distributions families like gaussian, poisson, binomial the parameters are directly available. For other distributions like negative binomial or gamma there is a conversion from GLM parameterization to standard distribution parameterization.

For example for gaussian family, the dependent variable is normally distributed with mean given by `results.fittedvalues` or `results.predict(x)` and variance given by `results.scale`

using `from scipy import stats`

```
    scale_n = scale / var_weights
    return stats.norm(loc=mu, scale=np.sqrt(scale_n))
```

https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/main/statsmodels/genmod/families/family.py#L675

Note:
`scale` in scipy.stats distributions corresponds to the standard deviation, while it corresponds to the variance in GLM and OLS.

`var_weights` are like `weights` in WLS for the case when variance differs across observations (heteroscedasticity). By default it is just ones like in OLS and can be ignored. (`var_weights` are currently only implemented for GLM.)
For non-gaussian families, `var_weights` is a multiplicative factor for the inherent heteroscedasticity where variance is a function of the mean.

Comment: Yes, all I am looking for is to get the predicted distribution from the fit.

Comment: I added the example for gaussian

Comment: Sorry. This makes sense except I am not sure what     scale is being divided by. What is var_weights

Comment: `var_weights` are like `weights` in WLS for the case when variance differs across observations (heteroscedasticity). By default it is just ones like in OLS and can be ignored.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html it looks like `rvs` is what should be used as opposed to `norm.stats`